# PHP multiple checked checkboxes from database

Tags: php, arrays, database, checkbox, while-loop

I am trying to generate a form with multiple checkboxes from a database. Right now only the last entry from the array is showing up. If there is supposed to be only one thing checked it works, but for more than one, only the last entry in the array shows up as checked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php
include "DBconnect.php";

$staffId = $_REQUEST["ID"];

$query=" select listCode from staffLabels
        where staffId = $staffId";

$result=$mysql->query($query);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    //in_array ()check if value is in array

    $b_checked='';
    $d_checked='';
    $x_checked='';
    $f_checked='';
    $c_checked='';
    if($row['listCode'] =="b") {$b_checked='checked';}
    elseif($row['listCode'] =="d") {$d_checked='checked';}
    elseif($row['listCode'] =="x") {$x_checked='checked';}
    elseif($row['listCode'] =="f") {$f_checked='checked';}
    elseif($row['listCode'] =="c") {$c_checked='checked';}


}
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="listCode[]" value="b" '.$b_checked.' >b';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="listCode[]" value="d"  '.$d_checked.' >d';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="listCode[]" value="x"  '.$x_checked.' >x';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="listCode[]" value="f"  '.$f_checked.' >f';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="listCode[]" value="c"  '.$c_checked.' >c<br /><br />';
?>
```

Comment: Try taking the 'declarations' out of the `while`. Each loop erases the previous content of the variables, keeping only the last one...

Comment: But, there are better ways of doing what you are trying to do...

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). If you're using MySQLi or PDO (which you should since the `mysql_*`-functions are deprecated), you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Or at the very least, `$staffId = $_REQUEST["ID"] + 0;` to force `$staffId` to a numeric value.

Comment: @AJNeufeld -  A more native way would be: `$staffId = (int) $_REQUEST['ID'];` :-) But yes, it does the same thing.

Comment: @FirstOne Taking out the declarations worked! Thanks! I am open to doing this a different way, I'm just new to PHP and don't really know how else to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
include "DBconnect.php";

$staffId = (int) $_REQUEST["ID"];

$query=" select listCode from staffLabels
        where staffId = $staffId";

$result=$mysql->query($query);
$checked=[];
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $checked[$row['listCode']]=true;
}

foreach(['b','d','x','f','c'] as $value){
    $chk=isset($checked[$value])?'checked':'';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='listCode[]' value='$value' $chk>";
}

echo "<br /><br />";
```